# Removing duplicates in List Control (MFC)

Tags: c++, mfc

So, I've been trying to prevent adding text/item duplicates in List Control (It is added by File Browser).. I'm developing a new dll injector for my custom needs and that's the only problem I face and I've been trying to fix, but it is still not the best option.

What I've been trying to do:

```
CFileDialog FileDialog(TRUE, L"*.*",    NULL, OFN_HIDEREADONLY, L"Dynamic Link Library (*.dll)|*.dll||");

    if (FileDialog.DoModal() == IDOK)
    {
        CString DllName = FileDialog.GetFileName();
        DllPathes.push_back(FileDialog.GetPathName());
        LVFINDINFO tempFind;
        tempFind.psz = DllName;
        tempFind.flags = LVFI_STRING;

        if (DllBox.FindItem(&tempFind))
        {
            DllBox.InsertItem(0, DllName);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your `DllBox` variable is the [`CListCtrl`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hfshke78%28v=vs.120%29.aspx), then I wonder why you are not checking the return value of [`FindItem`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4xetd6cd%28v=vs.120%29.aspx), as your current expression will always evaluate to true, except if the index is 0.

> **Return Value:**
>   The index of the item if successful or -1 otherwise.

```
if (DllBox.FindItem(&tempFind) == -1) //Not found !
{
    DllBox.InsertItem(0, DllName);
}
```

If you also store in the container `DllPathes` the newly selected path, why don't you search in this container too, and prevent it from being added ?

```
CString csSelected = FileDialog.GetPathName();
std::find(DllPathes.begin(), DllPathes.end(), [&](const CString &c)
                                              {return csSelected.Compare(c);});
```

You should also consider giving your variables a name which starts with a lowercase letter. Especially with MFC classes you can get confused fast.
Could `FileDialog` be a class which inherits from `CFileDialog`, or is it a variable ? *You can even see the formatting done by Stackoverflow* !

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that it's return value if it didn't find it -1, I though checking it regularly would get the job done. It is now working :)